# Why are my Neewer flash and trigger not working together?

Tags: off-camera-flash, compatibility

My Neewer NW-910 speedlight and Neewer Q-N transmitter are not working on my Nikon D3100. Can you help me?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

The Neewer NW910 has no radio communication built in and is **not** part of Neewer's Q system. The only lights in the Q system that you can remotely control over radio from a Q-N transmitter are (from [this Amazon listing](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08BHYWJCS)):

- Q3
- NW420
- NW655
- S101 Pro Flash Monolight

I would assume you could also use the Z1 (which is compatible with all these other lights and [the QPro-N](https://neewer.com/products/neewer-qpro-n-ttl-wireless-flash-trigger-for-nikon-66602087).

Neewer isn't really a manufacturer; they're a rebrander of gear from half a dozen different Chinese companies. So just because something is branded as Neewer doesn't guarantee it's compatible with other Neewer gear. With Neewer, it can be very difficult to find out what works with what; it's not nearly as well-defined or easy to research as, say, the Godox X system.